# Change video metadata

Tags: linux, video, metadata, exif

I have downloaded some videos that contain title metadata, which contains rubbish text.

This unfortunately causes vlc to display the title metadata when the video is played, instead of the file name.
Would it be possible to make a script that either deletes the title metadata, or at least forces it to be the same as the current filename ?

The videos come in various extensions, most of them are wmv.